# Select and group all figures in certain range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some (many) Excel workbooks where there are a lot of figures (lines, boxes, text boxes etc. drawn in a certain area (A1:Z32).

The combination of figures gives a complete drawing that I must work with (for instance copy-pasting, resizing etc).

I can select the figures one by one using <kbd>Shift</kbd> and left clicking on all the figures, then right click and select "Group". However, there are 10-20 figures that must be grouped, and it's very easy to miss a few if I'm manually selecting them.

Is there a way to make a boundary / select a range and select all figures contained in it (possible in Autocad, MS Paint and pretty much anything made for drawing. Unfortunately, Excel isn't).

Comment: You can Select/Group all Shapes whose **upper left-hand corner** is in a range.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I can't make that work. If I right click on the figure (either on one of the drawn items, or a cell) the range is no longer selected (only one element). If a range is selected then the "Range" button on the Format tab is grey.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around:

1. Select a range so that all figures are contained in that range
2. Copy those cells
3. Paste those cells into a new sheet. (Make sure the cells have the same dimension as the original sheet.
4. Select everything in the second sheet (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
5. Right click on one of the figure elements and select "Group".

Now it's possible to select the entire drawing as one figure, if you click on the edge of the group.

Comment: Other, cleaner options are much appreciated!